# Shopware 6: How to access plugin configuration from service?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm wring a service that fetches some data from an external url using an API Key.
The key is entered within the plugin configuration. Now I want to fetch that config variable from within my service - but how?

There is no config stuff within my vue component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the administration use the `systemConfigApiService` to fetch config values in vue components:

```js
Component.register('my-custom-component', {
    template,

    inject: ['systemConfigApiService'],

    methods: {
        async getPluginConfig() {
            const response = await this.systemConfigApiService.getValues('YourPluginName.config', salesChannelId);
            const apiKey = response['YourPluginName.config.apiKey'];
        },
    }
}
```

If you meant a PHP service inject `Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService`

```php
$this->systemConfigService->get('YourPluginName.config.apiKey', $salesChannelId)
```

The sales channel id is optional in both cases.